# Recording and uploading a video in IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, video

So far, I have found red5, but I can't get it to run (no video arrives at the server side), so I was looking for a flash-based getUserMedia and found: https://github.com/addyosmani/getUserMedia.js . But how do I get the video on the server? IE10 doesn't support webRTC, which http://lynckia.com/licode/ is built on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getUserMedia is a WebRTC API. It doesn't exist on IE10.

Your alternatives are

1. Go with a Flash based solution (red5, Wowza, etc)
2. Use a plugin for WebRTC on IE (check out this one: https://bloggeek.me/temasys-free-webrtc-plugin/
3. Use [Ziggeo](http://ziggeo.com/) (they should be able to use WebRTC or Flash automatically for you, taking care of all relevant transcoding and format changes necessary to playback the recorded stream). [CameraTag](http://www.cameratag.com/) (virtually the same at first glance) was also suggested in another answer, and likely, there are more.